# Add object into property of another object dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Object inside AJAX call and I'm not able to add new property to its property containing another object.

Here is my attempt:

```
$.post('/home/save.json', {obj:obj}, function(data) {
    var qu = {};
    qu["Id"] = "some value";
    qu["Type"] = "some value";
    qu["Name"] = "some value"
    qu["Variants"] = data["Variants"]
    if (data['Subvariant']) { 
        qu["Variants"]["Subvariant"] = data['Subvariant'] 
    }
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Are you sure that `data["Variants"]` is actually an object? What does the relevant part of your data (the JSON) look like? What you have will work as long as `data["Variants"]` is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some semicolons, and I would use dot notation

```
var qu = {};
qu.Id = "some value";
qu.Type = "some value";
qu.Name = "some value";
qu.Variants = data.Variants;
if (data.Subvariant !== undefined && data.Subvariant !== null) {
    qu.Variants.Subvariant = data.Subvariant;
}
```

Or are you maybe meaning to check `data.Variants.Subvariant`instead of `data.Subvariant`?

Comment: @Alega: There is no difference between dot and bracket notation. They are equivalent. It makes no sense that this code works but yours does not. You must have changed something else as well.